# TSV output not supported. Tesseract >=3.05 required

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I had a issue with tesseract version.

Error log:

> raise TSVNotSupported() pytesseract.pytesseract.TSVNotSupported: TSV
>   output not supported. Tesseract >=3.05 required

How do I install tesseract 3.05 ?

Answer (score -1):

To you tesseract, you must have Tesseract OCR (the program not the library) installed. This will then enable the python library to work as expected. Additionally, you need to add it to your path.

Comment: Then you probably will have to package it as a docker image to ensure your image has the program, the library relies on the program to provide the needed functionality, much like you must have Apache Spark installed to use pyspark or a database installed to use a database library to access the db. The library simply provides an interface to the program, which does the heavy lifting

Comment: I fully couldn't understand the concept.
Is there any tesseract upgrade ?

Comment: no there is a tesseract OCR program, check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software) https://opensource.google/projects/tesseract              
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract